# Viewing all SharePoint Sites?

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-site

Is it possible to view all the Sharepoint sites easily? - I've been searching forever but can't seem to find anything I'm after.

When opening SharePoint within Office365 I can see the 'Frequent Sites' but default and down the side, I can see Following & Recent. 
[image: Example what I can see;]

Now, I've had a good Google about this but all I could find was going to site settings then site hierarchy, but this only shows me one site as I believe it's within the main site.

Comment: So, is your intention to allow all users to see all public sites and let her the opportunity to access any of them in an easy way?

Comment: Yes - I need to find a way (an easy way) of users finding all the sites. I haven't come across anything that shows me this as of yet. I don't see why Sharepoint don't replace the 'Frequent Sites' page with all the sites that a user has access to.

Comment: Its the worst UI ever... I mean... If you cant get a list of the sharepoint sites from the sidebar!!... WTF... How are you supposed to create favourites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is actually pretty easy if you use search.
If you select "Everything" as a scope in your search box and type:
**contentclass:STS_site**
you will get all site collections in your tenant, that user has permissions to.

If you type:
**contentclass:STS_web**
you get all webs in all site collections.

you can then prepare a page, put Search web parts on it and predefine search query to show the required results.

hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

The new O365 admin center updated on 2-19-2019 has this feature available and you can export the data out.